# Using the OR operator inside an if or just else if?

Tags: java

Good morning/afternoon/night,

I'm writting a simple function which will return a boolean if the string given as an argument (in this case a two character code) is matched.

I was wondering which would be considered the "Best" way to go about this, would it be using a number of || operators within a single if like below:

```
private boolean isCodeSpecial(String code){
    if( code.equalsIgnoreCase("AA") ||
        code.equalsIgnoreCase("AB") ||
        code.equalsIgnoreCase("SS") ||
        code.equalsIgnoreCase("DD") ||
        code.equalsIgnoreCase("YY") ||
        code.equalsIgnoreCase("ZZ") ||
        code.equalsIgnoreCase("AX") ){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or perhaps using a series of else if statements like the below:

```
private boolean isCodeSpecial(String code){
    if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("AA")){
        return true;
    }else if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("AB")){
        return true;
    }else if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("SS")){
    return true;
    }else if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("DD")){
        return true;
    }else if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("YY")){
        return true;
    }else if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("ZZ")){
        return true;
    }else if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("AX")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not really concerned about performance in this application, as I know any gains/penalies will likely be minimal and almost unnoticable - but if possible I would like to know whats generally considered best practice for future reference. I guess the argument could be made that this is exactly what else if is for ?

Thanks in advance,

Edit: Forgot to mention that I am using Java 1.6 (so I dont beleive a simple switch is possible without the use of Enums ?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why use an `if` statement at all?

```
return code.equalsIgnoreCase("AA") ||
    code.equalsIgnoreCase("AB") ||
    code.equalsIgnoreCase("SS") ||
    code.equalsIgnoreCase("DD") ||
    code.equalsIgnoreCase("YY") ||
    code.equalsIgnoreCase("ZZ") ||
    code.equalsIgnoreCase("AX");
```

If you *really* want the `if` statements, then I'd definitely go with the first approach. It will perform exactly the same number of comparisons as the if/else/if/else code due to shortcircuiting - if the first operand of the `||` operator evaluates to `true`, then the second operand won't be evaluated... but it's a *lot* clearer.

Another alternative would be to create a fixed case-insensitive set so you could then say:

```
return VALID_CODES.contains(code);
```

You could do that with a `TreeSet`:

```
private static final Set<String> VALID_CODES =
    new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

static {
    VALID_CODES.add("AA");
    VALID_CODES.add("AB");
    VALID_CODES.add("SS");
    VALID_CODES.add("DD");
    VALID_CODES.add("YY");
    VALID_CODES.add("ZZ");
    VALID_CODES.add("AX");
}
```

Comment: I would make the `static` block shorter: `VALID_CODES.addAll(Arrays.asList("AA", "AB", "SS", "DD", "YY", "ZZ", "AX"));`

Comment: @Jesper: That was an option, yes. It's a shame that `TreeSet` doesn't accept both a collection *and* a comparator in the constructor, to be honest :(

Answer (score 1):

First case is the way to go, as lesser the code its better from readability and maintenance point of  view

In fact Jon suggestion is best if just if you just want to return Boolean as it involves even lesser code

Answer (score 1):

in your case I'd use a regexp:

```
return code.toUpperCase().matches( "(AA|AB|SS|DD|ZZ|XX|CC)" );
```

Answer (score 0):

An array with all these strings and a loop that goes trough and returns at the first true occurence would be even more maintainable (and less verbose).

Answer (score 0):

What is the possibility if we use a switch case ? Is that would be better ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that in this case I am using Java 1.6 and I beleive that its not possible to perform a `switch` on a `String` unless you are using 1.7+ - I beleive this can be worked around with 1.6 Enums though and thw `valueOf()` method

Answer (score 0):

considering both the best and worst case scemerios, both of your choices will be equally efficent because in both the cases same number of comparisons are to be performed... but as answered by jon first one will be little readable than the second one...

what if you also try switch case ... that will have a performance edge i guess..

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first way as it's more clearer and easier to read than the second one and also easy to maintain and does the exact same thing.

Additionally, you can try some thing even better in performance and easier to read - **Switch**

Here is how the same thing above will look as:

```
private static boolean isCodeSpecial(String code){
    switch(code.toUpperCase()){ //Convert code to upper case so that
        case "AA":              //you don't have to do case sensitive search
        case "AB":
        case "SS":
        case "DD":
        case "YY":
        case "ZZ":
        case "AX":
            return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

**Additional Note:**

> *You can only use Switch in java for **String** on **JDK 7 or later versions***. If you are using a **earlier version** of java, then **go for if else version**.